# Does anybody know how to translate Windows SDDL strings into Human readable format?

Tags: powershell, scripting, permissions, active-directory, network-printers

I have been recently trying to complete an audit on printers.

After completing a small slice of the work by manually putting in all the information into excel and almost losing my mind, I decided to take a different approach and learn how to use powershell to save time and effort, and also prepare a much more accurate and clean document in a considerably shorter time span.
I only have one problem...90% of the information is incredibly accurate, apart from the SDDL strings, which were quite cryptic.

I learned that there exists a way to translate them, via the ConvertFrom-SddlString function, but the output is still lacking the essential information I need:

- Group or Username (Example: Everyone; John Doe; All Application Packages; CREATOR OWNER; Admins; etc..)
- Permissions (Print, Manage this printer, Manage Documents, or any combination of these)

Example of the output I was trying to achieve from the SDDL strings: "[Everybody: Print; All Application Packages: Manage Documents; CREATOR OWNER: Print, Manage Documents; AdminY: Print, Manage documents, Manage this printer; AdminX: Print, Manage this printer]"

The ConvertFrom-AddlString seems to be lacking some groups, and also doesn't tell you some permissions. I tried manually writing a parser for the sddl string in powershell, but being a newbie in powershell I am finding myself quite lost.

I have scoured the internet looking for a function or some code that might be able to do just that but to no avail, and we are severely limited in programming within the company, so I cannot use any other programming languages I know to help me out.

Does anyone know if there is a way to translate the SDDL strings in a more reliable/accurate manner?

```
    $allprintservers = (Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(.......)" -properties *|Sort-Object -Unique -Property servername).servername 
    $prntrs = @()
    foreach ($printserver in $allprintservers){
        $pos = $printserver.IndexOf(".")
        $PrintServerName = $printserver.Substring(0, $pos)
        $printers = (Get-Printer -ComputerName $PrintServerName | Where-Object  {$_.Name -notlike "......."}).Name
        foreach ($printer in $printers) {
            if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($printer) -or $printer -like "........."){
                $printer = "null"
                break
            }else{
                $currentprinter = Get-Printer -ComputerName $PrintServerName | Where-Object  {$_.Name -like $printer}
                $name = $currentprinter.Name
                $location = $currentprinter.Location
                $comment = $currentprinter.Comment
                $driverName = $currentprinter.DriverName
                $sharedName = $currentprinter.ShareName
                $shared = $currentprinter.Shared
                $portName = $currentprinter.PortName
                $permissions = (Get-Printer -ComputerName $PrintServerName -name $name -Full).PermissionSDDL
                $translation = ConvertFrom-SddlString -sddl $permissions -type ActiveDirectoryRights | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DiscretionaryAcl
                $translation = [string]::join("; ",($translation.Split("`n")))
            }#else
            $prntr = [PSCustomObject]@{
                ServerName = $PrintServerName
                PrinterName = $name
                Location = $location
                Comment = $comment
                DriverName = $driverName
                SharedName = $sharedName
                Shared = $shared
                PortName = $portName
                UnTransACL = $permissions
                TransACL = $translation
            }#printer_CustomObject
            $prntrs += $prntr
        }#Foreach 2nd
    }#foreach 1st
    $prntrs | Export-Csv "..\..\PrinterAudit2022.csv" -Encoding UTF8
```

I have removed a very few select parts of the code to avoid sharing any sensitive information, but it shouldn't affect the logic of the code.

Comment: The ```DiscretionaryAcl```  property of the value returned by ```ConvertFrom-SddlString``` contains an array of principals and rights defined in the SDDL string - e.g. (on my pc at least) ```((get-acl c:\Windows).sddl | ConvertFrom-SddlString).DiscretionaryAcl[0]``` -> ```NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM: AccessAllowed (CreateDirectories, Delete, ExecuteKey, GenericExecute, GenericRead, GenericWrite, ListDirectory, Modify, Read, ReadAndExecute, ReadAttributes, ReadExtendedAttributes, ReadPermissions, Synchronize, Traverse, Write, WriteAttributes, WriteData, WriteExtendedAttributes, WriteKey)```

Comment: @mclayton I do see the same type of output, but when I go manually onto the print server, I see that (for example) "CREATOR OWNER" group/user is not visible in the output, but it actually is configured and visible when you go there manually. Also in some cases, a user has just "print" permissions, and another user (for the same exact printer) has "print" and "manage this printer" permissions, yet ConvertFrom-SddlString shows them as both having the same permissions. Some information seems to be lost when translating using ConvertFrom-SddlString function.

Comment: @Stefan The SDDL string has 4 components - an Owner, a Group, a DACL, and a SACL. In other words, the group/owner information is _not_ part of the DACL, so if that's all you ever inspect it won't paint you the full picture.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ahhh now I get it. Thank you for explaining that, I hadn't understood that.
Would know if there is any way to get a simpler picture? Effectively I need to see where mistakes were made in the configuration (which there are many) and a simple picture of the current conf. status would help a great deal in fixing mistakes made by previous engineers.

Comment: If you want to detect misconfigurations, the best thing you can do is _not_ to try and convert the SDDL strings to something "more humanly readable" - it's the computer that needs to be accurately configured, not a human :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I couldn't agree more ahaha if more attention to detail would have been used from the beginning, none of this work would be necessary. Unfortunately, though, due to the nature of the audit, I have to show the boss where the misconfigurations occurred, so I have the strong feeling I'll need to go and manually grab all that information :)